# Contextual filter - day of week in url

Tags: views

I'm looking for a way to only show elements related to a specific day in the week. Let's assume that the url to the view is: /program/schedule. What I would like is that when you go to: /program/schedule/monday,  only the info related to the monday is displayed.

Now I already figured out the contextual filters and that I can limit the valid values to: monday, tuesday, wednesday, et cetera. This is not the problem. The problem that I'm having is that it seems that my date time field needs to have an input of a specific date like 20130902.

I also need to point out that I am able to format my date time field to only show as a day of the week (with date formatting), but this does not seem to impact the contextual filter.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe with hooks or something custom?

Answer (score 0):

[Views Day of Week](https://drupal.org/project/views_dow) provides a simple filter plugin for Views 3 to enable filtering content that should be visible based on the current day of the week.

> Example: With this module you can select that some content should be
>   visible only on Mondays, some on Tuesdays and Thursdays and some only
>   on Fridays.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have the ability to create a field with a dropdown where you can select the day. The problem is that there only is a date time field (that holds the datetime when an event is shown). So the data is hold as a date time value, but true the input of the contextual filter, it should see the date time as a day of week (with or without the use of the date format that I put on the field). This module seems to need an extra field, and this is not what I want.